# Are these two structures of 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane enantiomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers, erratum

[image]

According to me they are not enantiomers because the mirror image can be rotated by  $180^\circ$ to get the same compound.
Giving it a little more 3-D look:

[image: my attempt]

But the book says they are enantiomers. I don’t understand how?

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: Related: [Does trans 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane have zero dipole moment?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39300/7951)

Comment: They are certainly *mirror images*, but since they are superimposable on each other, they are not *enantiomers*. http://goldbook.iupac.org/E02069.html

Comment: Like stated in the question Loong linked, there is also a mirror plane present.

Comment: The molecules are identical (i.e. the same substance)  not enatiomers.

Comment: [@Loong](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3068/7475)

Comment: “The books says” is somewhat better than “my book says” (to know that you didn't write it yourself), but it's still too incomplete bibliographical info.