# Symmetry of trans-1,3,dichlorocyclobutane

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image]

Is dis molecule having a plane?or inversion centre or what?and what is it's point group?

Comment: Remember dat dis molecule is puckered.

Comment: Related: [Does trans 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane have zero dipole moment?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/39300/7951) and [Are these two structures of 1,3-dichlorocyclobutane enantiomers?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43397/7951)